# 'Failed to rename directory' is the error that keeps popping up when I try installing Android SDK tools on the Android SDK manager

Tags: android, sdk, directory, rename

'Failed to rename directory' is the error that keeps popping up when I try installing Android SDK tools on the Android SDK manager, does anyone know how to fix this problem/error?

I've already tried to deactivate my anti-virus software but that didn't work

i expected the end result to be all is installed but, the Android SDK tools wont install.

Comment: Did you tried to run the "Android Studio" with Administrator previlage. ie, Right Click Android Studio link and "Run As Administrator".?

Comment: This didn't work